# How can I change the HFCLK to be controlled by a low frequency oscillator on my microprocessor?

Tags: c, embedded, clock, microprocessors

I am using an EFM32G222F128 Gecko microporcessor made by Energy Micro. I am trying to make the current consumption of this chip to be as low as possible and to do so I want to switch the core clock to use the low frequency RC oscillator (LFRCO) instead of the high frequency one.

I know that the core clock is driven by the high frequency clock (HFCLK) but this can be controlled by either a HF oscillator or a LF oscillator. By default it is set to be controlled by the HFRCO on reset / power on which has a frequency of 14MHz (again by default but this can be between 1MHz - 28MHz), my issue is the higher the frequency, the higher the current consumption of the chip so I want to change the core clock to this lower frequency oscillator which is 32.768KHz - much lower.

There are two on board oscillators - HFRCO and LFRCO - so it is not an issue with me not having the component available, I just don't know why the code I have at the moment is not working. Here is said code and I will explain it underneath:

```
int main(void){ 

    /* Chip errata */
    CHIP_Init();

    CMU->OSCENCMD = (1 << 6);          // Enable LFRCO oscillator
    while(!(CMU->STATUS & (1 << 7)));  // Wait for oscillator to stabilize

    EMU_UpdateOscConfig();

    CMU->CMD = (3 << 0);               // Set LFRCO as HF core clock **PROBLEM**

    CMU->OSCENCMD = (1 << 1);          // Disable HFRCO
}
```

As you can see there isn't a lot of code before the problem arises which may be part of the issue but I don't think that is the case. As, I hope, you can see from the comments, all this is doing is initialising the chip as you would with any PIC or microcontroller, I then enable to oscillator I wish to set as my core clock (LFRCO) and then wait for it to stabilise / be ready before moving on. I then update the processor to keep it informed of the changes to the clocks and then attempt to change the HFCLK to the LFRCO. This is where the program gives up on life and stops, it waits on this line of code for about 1 minute 30 seconds before, I assume, it times out and resets the chip as all of the registers reset to zero.

I am programming using C on Simplicity Studios which is designed for use with these chips and it comes with lots of pre-made libraries which I have also tried using to do this but they also don't work so I think I am just missing out something I need to do before trying to set it. I have scoured through the [reference manual](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/EFM32G-RM.pdf) as well as the application notes on oscillators / clocks but I can't see anything that I am missing.
I have made a list of everything have done before trying to set it and still nothing:

- I enable the oscillator
- I make sure it is ready to be used
- I have tried calibrating it (shouldn't need to be done as it is done at production but I tried anyway)
- I update the processor
- Then it crashes.

I have looked at all of the registers while stepping through the code and everything seems to be as it should, the oscillator is enabled and I can set it to be the source of something else so it does definitely work, just not for what I want it to.

I am sort of running out of ideas and I was hoping someone might have had a similar issue in the past and would be able to shed some light on this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using the EFM32 library with `EMU_UpdateOscConfig()`, I am not sure why you would not simply use [`CMU_ClockSelectSet( cmuClock_CORE, cmuSelect_LFRCO )`](http://downloads.energymicro.com/documentation/doxygen/group__CMU.html#g25eeb866651aacd0716f06e956728d73)?  I would suggest that if you use the library at all, you use it for everything rather than mix library use with direct register access.

Looking at the [source code](http://downloads.energymicro.com/documentation/doxygen/efm32__cmu_8c-source.html#l00850) for `CMU_ClockSelectSet()`, it does a number of things that you are not doing, or are doing in a different order.